# How to return different cache-control headers for different endpoints using ASP.NET minimal APIs?

Tags: c#, asp.net, minimal-apis

I would like to return a different cache-control header value for different endpoints using ASP.NET minimal APIs.  How do we do this without controllers?

This can be accomplished using controllers as follows:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace CacheTest;

[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet, Route("cache"), ResponseCache(Duration = 3600)]
    public ActionResult GetCache() => Ok("cache");

    [HttpGet, Route("nocache"), ResponseCache(Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult GetNoCache() => Ok("no cache");
}
```

The first endpoint returns the header `Cache-Control: public,max-age=3600`.

The second endpoint returns the header `Cache-Control: no-cache,max-age=0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`RequestDelegate` overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.endpointroutebuilderextensions.mapget#microsoft-aspnetcore-builder-endpointroutebuilderextensions-mapget(microsoft-aspnetcore-routing-iendpointroutebuilder-system-string-microsoft-aspnetcore-http-requestdelegate)) which allows you to interact with the `HttpContext` and `HttpResponse` so that you can set cache headers, like this:

```cs
app.MapGet("/", httpContext =>  
{
    httpContext.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
        "public,max-age=" + 3600;
    return Task.FromResult("Hello World!");
});
```

You could write a simple extension method to add that for you, like

```cs
public static class HttpResponseExtensions
{
    public static void AddCache(this HttpResponse response, int seconds)
    {
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] =
            "public,max-age=" + 10000;
    }

    public static void DontCache(this HttpResponse response)
    {
        response.Headers[HeaderNames.CacheControl] = "no-cache";
    }
}
```

...which makes your minimal API method less verbose:

```cs
app.MapGet("/", httpContext =>  
{
    httpContext.Response.AddCache(3600);
    // or
    httpContext.Response.DontCache();

    return Task.FromResult("Hello World!");
});
```